# Do I need proprietary drivers or intel microcode to be installed on new PC running 18.04?

Tags: drivers, sound, graphics, lubuntu

For my new Desktop PC build, based on intel i5-8400, with MSI H310M-VH mobo, 8GB DDR4 Crucial RAM, SATA HDD (no SSD yet, but that I plan to add in some time), and using the Integrated Graphics Processor (i5 based, i.e. Intel HD Ultra 630), i.e. no discrete GPU, I have installed Lubuntu 18.04 to maximize the performance from the system, as my main usage of this system is for music production, and apart from that also running virtual cluster (on KVM) of few VMs, software development etc.

Everything works out of the box, and have not had to do much tinkering (except for a bit for LAN interface) with proprietary drivers, installing intel i5 latest microcode etc. In fact, I've almost never have had to use proprietary drivers in several PC's I've built or few Laptops I've owned/used which have been running Lubuntu. Thus wondering if there is some performance or additional feature, better stability to be unlocked by installing and using proprietary drivers s.a. for:

- onboard IGP (Intel Ultra HD 630, in intel i5-8400)
- onboard LAN (Realtek RTL8111H Gigabit LAN controller)
- onboard sound (Realtek ALC887 Codec - 7.1)

Kindly note that for music production work I plan to replace the generic kernel with a lowlatency kernel and hopefully the usage of proprietary drivers (if I go down that route), shall not interfere (I hope).

Comment: You don't need any proprietary drivers for this hardware. Microcode is not related at all.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Pilot6. Reason for mentioning microcode is that I watched a Mint Cinnamon 18.3 review video where the reviewer covers the proprietary drivers and also intel microcode in the same section of the SW installation menu. Was also a bit curious to cover my back against the relatively recent vulerabilities -- Spectra, Meltdown etc., so the look at microcode. Also could be great to know the reason why you believe that I shouldn't need any proprietary drivers for this hardware ?  Is it because recent kernels are known to offer support for them out-of-the-box ?

Comment: The answer is obvious: there are no proprietary Linux drivers for these pieces of hardware.

Comment: Microcode is related, because it affects operation of the Intel GPU which is part of the CPU. You should also have it installed, to help ensure your system remains secure. It's also been my experience that video acceleration does not work as well without it, when using Intel video.

Comment: Thanks @dobey. I will check to see if there is relevant microcode to be installed in this case, and ensure that the 3d acceleration works to the best of it's abilities.

Comment: @Pilot6, apparently there is a specific proprietary driver for the GB-eth-LAN device available here (http://www.realtek.com.tw/Downloads/downloadsView.aspx?Conn=4&DownTypeID=3&Langid=1&Level=5&PFid=5&PNid=13). Also, the kernel default RTL8169 driver didn't work well for me, but RTL8168 (available as DKMS) works much better for it.